# Getting a "String index out of range: -1" error

Tags: java

This method is supposed to switch the first letter of the string with the last letter

```
public static String frontBack(String str)
{
    return (str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()) + str.substring(1, str.length()-1) + str.substring(0, 1));
}
```

I run the code, and it compiles fine and returns the correct output, but I get an error message saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1".

Through some testing, I found that the part of the code causing this issue is str.substring(1, str.length()-1), but I have no idea why. (1, str.length()-1) should be within range.

The argument passed is "code", if that matters.

for reference, the whole code is

```
public class Methodical {
    /*
     * Given two int values, returns their sum.
     * Unless the two values are the same, then return double their sum.
     * sumDouble(1, 2) → 3
     * sumDouble(3, 2) → 5
     * sumDouble(2, 2) → 8
     */

    public static int sumDouble(int a, int b)
    {
        if(a == b)
        {
            return 2 * (a + b);
        }
        else
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Given 2 ints, a and b, return true if one of them is 10
     * or if their sum is 10.
     * makes10(9, 10) → true
     * makes10(9, 9) → false
     * makes10(1, 9) → true
     */

    public static boolean makes10(int a, int b) 
    {
        if(a == 10 || b == 10 || (a+b) == 10)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * We have two monkeys, a and b, and the parameters
     * aSmile and bSmile indicate if each is smiling.
     * We are in trouble if they are both smiling
     * or if neither of them is smiling.
     * Return true if we are in trouble.
     * monkeyTrouble(true, true) → true
     * monkeyTrouble(false, false) → true
     * monkeyTrouble(true, false) → false
     */

    public static boolean monkeyTrouble(boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) 
    {
        if((aSmile == true && bSmile == true) || (aSmile == false & bSmile == false))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*Return true if the given non-negative number is a multiple of 3
    * or a multiple of 5. Use the % "modulus" operator
    * or35(3) → true
    * or35(10) → true
    * or35(8) → false
    * */

    public static boolean or35(int a) 
    {
        if(a % 3 == 0 || a % 5 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Given a string, return a new string where "not " has been added to the front.
     * However, if the string already begins with "not", return the string unchanged.
     * notString("candy") → "not candy"
     * notString("x") → "not x"
     * notString("not bad") → "not bad"
     */

    public static String notString(String str) 
    {
        if(str.length() >= 3)
        {
            if(str.substring(0, 3).equals("not"))
            {
                return str;
            }
            else
            {
                return ("not " + str);
            }
        }

        else
            return ("not " + str);
    }

    /*
     * Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged
     * frontBack("code") → "eodc"
     * frontBack("a") → "a"
     * frontBack("ab") → "ba"
     */

    public static String frontBack(String str)
    {
        return (str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()) + str.substring(1, str.length()-1) + str.substring(0, 1));
    }

    /*
     * We'll say that a number is "teen" if it is in the range 13..19 inclusive.
     * Given 3 int values, return true if 1 or more of them is/are teen.
     * hasTeen(13, 20, 10) → true
     * hasTeen(20, 19, 10) → true
     * hasTeen(20, 10, 13) → true
     */

    public static boolean hasTeen(int num1, int num2, int num3) 
    {
        if(num1 >= 13 && num1 <= 19 || num2 >= 13 && num2 <= 19 || num3 >= 13 && num3 <= 19)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }




    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int result;
        boolean answer;
        String value;
        System.out.println("***Testing sumDouble***\n");
        result = sumDouble(1, 2);
        System.out.println("Should print 3: " + result);
        result = sumDouble(3, 2);
        System.out.println("Should print 5: " + result);
        result = sumDouble(2, 2);
        System.out.println("Should print 8: " + result +"\n");

        System.out.println("***Testing makes10***\n");
        answer = makes10(9, 10);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = makes10(9, 9);
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + answer);
        answer = makes10(1, 9);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer + "\n");

        System.out.println("***Testing monkeyTrouble***\n");
        answer = monkeyTrouble(true, true);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = monkeyTrouble(false, false);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = monkeyTrouble(true, false);
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + answer + "\n");

        System.out.println("***Testing or35***\n");
        answer = or35(3);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = or35(10);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = or35(8);
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + answer + "\n");

        System.out.println("***Testing notString***\n");
        value = notString("candy");
        System.out.println("Should be not candy: " + value);
        value = notString("x");
        System.out.println("Should be not x: " + value);
        value = notString("not bad");
        System.out.println("Should be not bad: " + value + "\n");

        System.out.println("***Testing frontBack***\n");
        value = frontBack("code");
        System.out.println("Should be eodc: " + value);
        value = frontBack("a");
        System.out.println("Should be a: " + value);
        value = frontBack("ab");
        System.out.println("Should be ba: " + value + "\n");


        System.out.println("***Testing hasTeen***\n");
        answer = hasTeen(13, 20, 10);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = hasTeen(20, 19, 10);
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = hasTeen(20, 10, 13) ;
        System.out.println("Should be true: " + answer);
        answer = hasTeen(20, 10, 45) ;
        System.out.println("Should be false: " + answer + "\n");

        System.out.println("***End of Tests***");

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) One key aspect is to include only a [mcve], not **all** of your code. Also describe what research you've done to try to resolve/understand the problem, etc. You're clearly providing incorrect indexes to `substring`. String indexes are 0 through length-1, inclusive, but at some stage you're asking `substring` to access an invalid character index. So you need to step through the code in your debugger to see when you're doing that.

Comment: (Hint: `"a".substring(1, "a".length - 1)` is `"a".substring(1, 0)`, which is asking for substring to get the character at `[1]`. But `"a"` only has a character at `[0]`.)

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown If the `begin Index` is less than zero OR `begin Index` > `end Index` OR `end Index` is greater than the length of String.

In your case I guess you are passing a string where `begin Index` > `end Index` (i.e string of length 1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it may be your problem. Have you checked if the input of your function is an empty String ("")? Or the input String could be a String of a single character.

I suggest you to add a validation on the input String:

```
public static String frontBack(String str)
{
    if(str.length() <= 1) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return (str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()) + str.substring(1, str.length()-1) + str.substring(0, 1));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account that there will be empty chains and chains with only one character!

This is the code correct!

```
public static String frontBack(String str)
    {
        if(str != null && str.length() > 1) {
            return (str.substring(str.length()-1, str.length()) + str.substring(1, str.length()-1) + str.substring(0, 1));
        } else {
            return str;
        }

    }
```